# Russian Samovar

Tags: перевод

I just bought a Russian samovar, and cannot read this type of Russian script...  could you provide the modern Russian script?   Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely a manufacturer's mark, in old (pre-revolutionary) Russian orthography.

It reads:

- ЯКОВЪ = Яков = Yakov ~ Jacob (probably the first name of manufacturer)
- НЕГИНСКИ = Neginski (probably the last name, but due to the fact that the caption is extremely weared off, it might had more letters before or after that originally)
- ВЪ ТУЛѢ = В Туле = in [Tula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tula,_Russia), city of origin, the main manufacturing center for samovars

Comment: Why Негински? Shouldn't it be Негинский in Russian? Can it be an American forgery?

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much!  This is more than likely from around the early 1800's...  It came with a note, that said in the 1930's, ceremonial teas were often organized by the  committee ladies to raise money for the Russian Room.  After the room was completed, several old Russian brass samovars were donated to the treasures.  This was one of them.
I like to restore old samovars... This is the first Russian one I purchased...
Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexVB Those kind of surnames have Polish origin, twice so when with Jewish name of Jacob. And in Poland they would indeed be written as "-ski". Now, after full russification those surnames would be seen as kind of possessive case and would end with "-скiй" rather than "-ский". See [part 1.4](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8) and [a photo](http://naar.ru/upload/medialibrary/5b0/5b032f18d7781054eb12dab86e3af880.jpg). Similar [geographic terms](http://ligovo-spb.ru/img/ludi/mertanen-n-k_tsarskaya-gramota-1916.jpg)

Comment: BTW, when searching in Yandex for such a name - this pops up: http://www.jewage.org/wiki/ru/Profile:P0160698533 - i think it reinforces my idea, that the surname was Jewish and came from Poland. Perhaps there is was seen in its original not yet totally russified form.

Comment: @Arioch My doubt is that the unrussificated form could exist and written as such, especially in Tula. But I have nothing to support the doubt.

Comment: @AlexVB there also could be "Й" totally non-printed, if we suppose then grammatically flawed "-СКИЙ" ending. Without extra documents we can only speculate.... Even if that is forgery, why it should be American one rather than Russian forgery back in 19th century? Anything is possible.

Comment: @Arioch the forgery suspicion i guess is based on the surname spelling, another question is whether Jews would engage in this type of craft, but the likelihood of it being Jewish could be reinforced by the fact that Jewish craftsmen assigned to specific workshops were allowed to reside outside of the Jewish Pale and thus in Тула

Comment: *Яковъ Чегински въ Тулѣ* ("Yakov Cheginski in Tula") https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/3409/xium.15/0_28207_e95d87a_orig